# Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoResponsiveGrid is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a Rails app and I want to use React components to make it look better. I want to use this [React library](https://github.com/xudafeng/autoresponsive-react) called `autoresponsive-react` but it won't render the component because it insists that the component named `AutoResponsiveGrid` is undefined. I have used other React libraries but this one is giving me lots of trouble.

I installed the library like it told me to, using:

```
npm i autoresponsive-react --save-dev
```

However, when I try to call the React component using the Rails `react_component` function, it tells me that `AutoResponsiveGrid is not defined`.

My `package-lock.json`:

```
 . . . 
    "autoresponsive-core": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoresponsive-core/-/autoresponsive-core-1.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-sNmRjQWslRJFOHRF7tEtqHU4MH4FDHN46vYdScfYRctSkCc4Ksqs5jKiDRXkFIdSJ4XWWcboq92567S74IKFSQ==",
      "dev": true
    },
    "autoresponsive-react": {
      "version": "1.1.31",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoresponsive-react/-/autoresponsive-react-1.1.31.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-aHzbT8Zr5Aaj0uQ6Zbf5552ojwTrfc3smOr8QW2ng9iAB6UxGRyYBg3jAvsezICzvLlmFk0g+n3i0px8SUS3Vw==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "autoresponsive-core": "^1.0.1",
        "exenv": "^1.2.0"
      }
    },
 . . .
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sample_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react_ujs": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoresponsive-react": "^1.1.31",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

My `progress.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    yaeoiajsdlfjadlskfjadlksjf
    </head>
    <body>
        <%-# Responsive Grid Here -%>
        <div>
            <%= react_component("AutoResponsiveGrid") %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My `AutoResponsiveGrid.js`:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import AutoResponsive from 'autoresponsive-react';
class AutoResponsiveGrid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AutoResponsive ref="container">
      </AutoResponsive>
    );
  }
}

export default AutoResponsiveGrid
```

As you can see, `AutoResponsive` div is empty, so I'm simply trying to use this React library, and it tells me it is undefined in this [Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/a92a7cc030665946c493286dd3334c3d).

I have called another React library, namely [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar), using the `react_component` function call and it works fine. Therefore, I don't think it is an issue of the `react_component`.

Also, my Heroku logs also tell me that the `autoresponsive-react` module is missing as shown in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/wangjess/a74a70deb411a6654aaa106f5a81e8a4).

Things I Have Tried: Deleting `package-lock.json` and recreating it using `npm install` and re-installing the React library.

Comment: Try `import * as AutoResponsive from 'autoresponsive-react';` Or, just simply run `console.log(AutoResponseive)` to see if it's even importing

Comment: @mwilson It does import something: https://gyazo.com/8b30ebef30c3331e541e1f847b24d9fa. I called `console.log(AutoResponsive)` right before the render() function.